# NewLine in HTML editor leaves a space in website

Tags: html, indentation

How can i use newlines in editor without having annoying spaces in my template?

There is an example of what i mean:

```
<nav id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[Fiddle1: newlines = annoying spaces](http://jsfiddle.net/zo492g3y/)

```
<nav id="navbar">
<ul><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li><li><a href="#"></a></li></ul>
</nav>
```

[Fiddle2: no newlines = perfect result](http://jsfiddle.net/bym9ghqt/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `float: left;`

```
#navbar ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zo492g3y/1/

A complete guide removing white space between inline-blocks could be found at: [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Comment: This will solve my specific problem, but isn't there a more generic way to avoid that spacing?

Answer (score 2):

use HTML comment, is another option if you want your code to be readable

```
<nav id="navbar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#"></a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#"></a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the `enter` key is the same as pressing `space`, as long as their is no `float:left`.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't leave your HTML pretty to read, but will solve the problem without resorting to css hacks etc...

```
<nav id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li><li>
        <a href="#"></a></li><li>
        <a href="#"></a></li><li>
        <a href="#"></a></li><li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `margin-left:` an a negative value